# Why do my Snort logs appear to be empty?

Tags: snort

So I was following [this guide](http://www.symmetrixtech.com/articles/016-snortinstallguide2953.pdf) on how to install Snort, Barnyard 2 and the like.

I've set up Snort so it would run automatically, by editing the rc.local file:

```
ifconfig eth1 up

/usr/local/snort/bin/snort -D -u snort -g snort \
-c /usr/local/snort/etc/snort.conf -i eth1
/usr/local/bin/barnyard2 -c /usr/local/snort/etc/barnyard2.conf \
-d /var/log/snort \
-f snort.u2 \
-w /var/log/snort/barnyard2.waldo \
-D
```

And I then restarted the computer. Snort was able to run and detect the attack, but the log files (including barnyard2.waldo) remained blank, even if a new log entry was created for each attack.

I'm not sure what went wrong here, since it's supposed to log any attacks and store it in the log directory, right?

Then, I tried changing the parameter to:

```
    /usr/local/snort/bin/snort -D -b -u snort -g snort \
-c /usr/local/snort/etc/snort.conf -i eth1
```

And when I checked the log file, there are two log files, one in u2 and another in tcpdump format, but they're both blank and is approximately 0 bytes.

So I thought I'd run it from the console to see if it would work from there, using this command:

```
/usr/local/snort/bin/snort -A full -u snort -g snort \

-c /usr/local/snort/etc/snort.conf -i eth1
```

and I then checked the log file to see if it would log the attack, and it still doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the permissions of the logfiles and the logdirectory.

possible snort is not able to write into that file/directory

Comment: Here's what the file permissions look like in /var/log/snort

`ls -l /var/log/snort
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  0 Mei  12 23:52 alert
-rw-r--r-- 1 snort snort 0 Apr  26 17:51 barnyard2.waldo
-rw------- 1 snort snort 0 Mei  13 08:58 snort.log.1399942704
-rw------- 1 snort snort 0 Mei  13 09:00 snort.log.1399942834
-rw------- 1 snort snort 0 Mei  13 21:02 snort.log.1399986140`

Comment: @hdr please change the permissions so you are able to write in the directory.
for a short test do chmod o+w /var/log/snort and restart snort. (maybe /var/ and /var/log/ aswell)
this is just for testing!
when this works you should change either the snort user or the permissions for /var/log/snort/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the internet connection crapped out the whole day for some reason. But, when I tried your suggestion is still doesn't work. However, when I started Snort from the console instead from a Daemon, I noticed this:

`Reputation config: WARNING: Can't find any whitelist/blacklist entries. Reputation Preprocessor disabled.` Do you think this might be the cause of the problems?

Comment: Update: So I re-downloaded the Snort Ruleset file and recreated and reconfigured the entries, (and also applied chmod on the /var/ directory), but it seems the problem's still there.

Comment: sorry out of ideas, the error you get seems to be not related to your issue based on a few google entries.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have `nostamp` specified in your snort.config. Find the line `output unified2: filename snort.log, limit 128` and make sure it doesn't look like:
`output unified2: filename snort.log, limit 128, nostamp`